# Complex protractor selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am developing an angular application and want to test it using protractor. I have a repeater inside a repeater.

I select the first repeater like so:

```
var firstRepeater = element.all(by.repeater('item in set'));
```

Now, I see that protractor does not support a syntax like:

```
var secondRepeater = firstRepeater.element.all(by.repeater('item in set2'))
```

This throws an exception telling me that **all** is not defined. So if I understand correctly, one can only use **firstRepeater.element** and not **firstRepeater.element.all** ?

Then how can I select an item in the second repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. As I found out, it's actually

```
var secondRepeater = firstRepeater.all(by.repeater('item in set2'))
```

instead of

```
var secondRepeater = firstRepeater.element.all(by.repeater('item in set2'))
```